# Write and Read a json data to internal storage android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, file

I have a json array received from php

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Daniel Bryan",
      "img":"pictures\/smallest\/dierdrepic.jpg",
      "username":"@dbryan",
      "user_id":"4"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Devil Hacker",
      "img":"pictures\/smallest\/belitapic.jpg",
      "username":"@dvHack",
      "user_id":"1"
   }
]
```

- What i want is to *write* this data in a `file_name.anyextension` in
  my apps data folder or anywhere safe.
- Also read this data from `file_name.anyextension` and convert it to a
  valid `json array` that can be further edited.

Can anyone show me a way how can i possibly to this thing ?

Comment: I assume you have googled 'java read/write data to file' so what have you tried so far?

Comment: `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("FileName.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println(myjsonstring);
writer.close();` @beresfordt

Comment: Could you put your efforts so far into the question body, and explain how it is not working

Comment: @beresfordt i have a `json array` how to write it in a file ? Its only `string` that could be written

Comment: How would you turn that json array into a string and print it to sysout?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}


private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("config.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

When read string from file convert it to JsonObject or JsonArray

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(str);
```

Comment: `The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type` & 
`The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type `

Comment: If the class is not extended from Activity, usage of the "openFileInput()" method should be like this: context.openFileInput()

Comment: Ya got that fixed though i have a `JSONArray` and not a `String` to write in a file @mortezasoeimani

Comment: use `jsonArrayObject.toString()` to get the string for saving in the file

Comment: use context.openFileOutput("myJson.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) and InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("myJson.txt").  :)

Answer (score 5):

Corrected answer of Morteza Soleimani for reading:

```
public static String readFromFile(String path) {
    String ret = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("FileToJson", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("FileToJson", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I don't use context, which changes a lot. 
You can't use path in previous code, test it yourself.