# how to read json array from internal storage and send http request?

Tags: android, json

i need a clarification of http connection.i can read my json object from internal memory.how to send http request ?
 i have to send send request in background simultaniously once send the data after that it will be going to empty till when next data will come to that file .
here my code is

```
package example.json.com.jsonarray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String data="";
    try {
        BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"mservice/database/queue_mgr.txt")));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        try {
            JSONArray  jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                data+=jsonObject.toString();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textView.setText("");
            textView.append("\n\n-----START CONTENT-----\n\n");
            textView.append(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kalai Prakash, first let me clear about your question. You are trying to call an API or something else locally or from a server?

Comment: i am doing a offline application.i was stored my data in internal storage.it was json array in text file. i have to send http request to the server when the internet is available.once send the data it will going to empty array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write and Read a json data to internal storage android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646757/write-and-read-a-json-data-to-internal-storage-android)

Comment: i can read the json but how to send the http request to the server

Comment: @KalaiPrakash Which network client you are using?

Comment: FTP server am using

Comment: ??? The question was :which client'. Not 'which server'. Anyhow in the subject of your post you are talking about a http request. Confused?