# IO exception when file is already present - Gson Android

Tags: android, exception, gson

I'm trying to parse a local json file called "category.json" but when I call the file I get an "Unhandled IO Exception" error. I have created the category.json file as well.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_menu, container, false);

    String jsonArray="category.json";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Category> list = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonArray), new TypeToken<List<Category>>(){}.getType());


    RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),list);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
    myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

I even tried using the AssetManager I still get the same error

```
    AssetManager assetManager =getContext().getAssets();
    InputStream is = assetManager.open("category.json");
```

Comment: Where have you placed `category.json` file?

Comment: I have placed it on my assets folder.

Comment: refer url it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483601/read-content-of-json-file-from-internal-storage/40483701#40483701

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the `IOException` using a `try - catch` as follows,

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
    InputStream is = assetManager.open("category.json");

    // do something with your stream

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Read more about exception handling [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-in-java).

Similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945411/android-java-how-can-i-parse-a-local-json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listvi).

Comment: I tried handling it. But that doesn’t read the file. So i tried directly running it instead. The problem is why it doesn’t read the json file