# Modifying parcelable object to modify reference in previous activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app that requires me to pass a reference to an object between multiple activities and modify it. Those modifications need to reflect the object throughout all activities. However, I'm not that familiar with Parcelable objects, and I'm running into some issues with my implementation of this.

So I have the "Character Main" activity:

```
public class CharacterMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CharacterInfo myCharacter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_character_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        myCharacter = (CharacterInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra("character");
        setTitle(myCharacter.getCharacterName());
    }

    public void openCharacterSheet(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CharacterSheetActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("character", myCharacter);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And then in the "Character Sheet" activity, it takes that Parcelable and creates its own reference, which it modifies through the use of several fields:

```
public class CharacterSheetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CharacterInfo myCharacter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_character_sheet);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        myCharacter = (CharacterInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra("character");
        if(myCharacter != null) {
            { // Set the character ability scores and modifiers.
                EditText strInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sheet_strength_input);
                strInput.setText(String.valueOf(myCharacter.getAbilityScore(AbilityScore.Scores.STRENGTH)
                                                           .getScoreValue()));
                strInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if(!s.toString().isEmpty() && s.toString().matches("\\d+")) {
                            myCharacter.setAbilityScore(AbilityScore.Scores.STRENGTH,
                                    Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                            TextView mod = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sheet_str_mod_label);
                            mod.setText("Mod: " + myCharacter.getAbilityScore(AbilityScore.Scores.STRENGTH)
                                    .getScoreModifier());
                        }
                    }
                });

                TextView modText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sheet_str_mod_label);
                modText.setText("Mod: " + myCharacter.getAbilityScore(AbilityScore.Scores.STRENGTH)
                                                     .getScoreModifier());
            } // End ability score set.
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I press the BACK button to return to the previous activity (in the case of Character Sheet, it returns to Character Main), and then go back to Character Sheet, the value I just changed is back to what it was before.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to accomplish this? I know things would be a lot simpler with a global static reference to the object, but I want to get this working the right way. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you should use Shared Preference and then change the values and retrieve it whenever you want. When you go back to your MainActicity, It still holds your latest changed value.

Comment: Except that these aren't preferences, and that seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: No its not complicated, when you need to store temporary values that you need in every activity, You can also use preferences. Instead of using Static variables.

Comment: But they're not temporary. I'm going to then store the information in a file. And the application needs to support multiple "characters". Preferences will not solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, thats another good option to persist data. Store your data in Json file. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646757/write-and-read-a-json-data-to-internal-storage-android or use  json-simple library https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: I was thinking maybe SQLite, but won't that make it slower and more bothersome for updating/reading data?

Comment: No it won't be slow. I'm assuming your data isn't that much, not up to 5000 . You might thinking of database optimization once your data starts getting more than a 1000.

Comment: It's quite a bit of data, actually. It's a class used to represent characters from 5th Edition D&D, if that means anything to you.

Comment: Yes, even so. i think you should use SQLite. But If you are still worried about Speed. Then you should consider using Realm.io, Its a better option to SQLite:  https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm/ and https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: then pass a custom `Binder` class object reference from one place to another

Comment: I appreciate the alternate suggestions, but I was really hoping someone could actually tell me why what I'm doing doesn't work, as opposed to suggesting complicated alternatives. I'd prefer to stick to what I know as opposed to researching several new methods, as I'm on a time constraint.

Comment: passing `Parcelable` is like creating a copy of the original object so the copy has nothing to do with the original (except all the fields are equal at the time of reading from `Parcel`)

Comment: Is there any way to get the actual object, rather than a copy? Or does using Parcels make what I want to do impossible?

Comment: pass a custom `Binder`

Comment: I tried Googling that to no avail. Do you know of a tutorial that could explain what they are and how to use them?